# How to change copy/paste toolbar position in Flutter

Tags: flutter

when popup the copy/paste toolbar in flutter TextField, the tool bar on top of cutout. this is the link
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37501

any ideas how to custom the position?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by Google. Actually, it is a bug of Flutter